# Disable iAd for a live app remotely

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I need to disable iAd in my app that is already live on the App Store. I know that I can just release an update that doesn't have ads, but I'm hoping to avoid the review delay. Is there any way to disable the app receiving ads in the iAd dashboard?

If it matters, the app hasn't been approved for iAds yet (they aren't showing up yet).

Comment: You can set the application to now show up in certain locations. This would remove it from the store until you get a new version up. I have never seen an option to shut the ads specifically once it is live without pushing a new version.

Comment: @Pyraego.com: You mean remove it from sale until the update goes out? I had already thought of that as an option, was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: Yea thats what I am referring too. Cant think of another way. Hope someone else chimes in.

Comment: @Pyraego.com: Yeah. It's not too bad if I have to do an update, and I could always try an expedited review, but even so. Still, I just wanted to see if there was a better solution.